# Codenameone Camera Component Customizing

Tags: camera, codenameone

all!

Is there any way to build custom camera component in codename one?

I googled and got about PeerComponents, however don't know how to use it.

I just would like to use it as Label component with 2 buttons (Taking picture button and retaking picture button)

Kindly provide some small sample code for me. Best regards.

**[UPDATE]**

I need this because of following reason.

First of all, I need square Image taken by camera, and user should be able to know how the picture will be taken.

2 resolutions here:

First, if I have to use full screen camera, it will be better to draw or overlay square rectangle on camera view so that user can know which area will be taken.

Second, if overlaying and drawing is difficult (or should use native code for that), I need some custom components for camera area such like PeerComponent. So I would like to place it anywhere of screen area as square rectangle. Then, users won't need any overlay or drawing something on it because it is already square.

That's all what I need.

Regards.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use the existing Capture API in CN1 for this?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's certainly possible to create a component like this, and we do intend to create one at some point in the future.  You can beat us to the punch.

First, you should familiarize yourself with how native interfaces work.  This video is a good start:

https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

This series of blog posts demonstrates how to wrap 3rd party SDKs into codename one on Android and iOS.

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-2.html
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-3.html

Although it doesn't include an example with PeerComponent, it is helpful for getting a grasp on the process.  Adding peer components into the mix is really just a matter of returning the corresponding "View" type from a native interface.  On Android, that is an `android.view.View`, on iOS it is a `UIView`, in Javascript it is an DOM element, in UWP it is a FrameworkElement, and in the simulator, it is a `javax.swing.JComponent`.

This blog post does include an example of a peer component, but it is targeting UWP:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/uwp-native-interfaces-mix-c-java.html

Once you have a grasp of the material, you should look at relevant examples.  Currently the most complete example I'm aware of of a cn1lib that implements a native peer is the Google Maps lib:

https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps

You can see the Android native implementation [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/blob/master/GoogleMaps/native/android/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsImpl.java), and the iOS native implementation [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/blob/master/GoogleMaps/native/ios/com_codename1_googlemaps_InternalNativeMapsImpl.m)

You may want to refer to the existing code for image capture in Codename One as well.

Android: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L5788-L5811
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L5701-L5714

Though it uses intent to open the native capture dialog, so it may not be too relevant.

IOS: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/IOSNative.m#L2879-L2927